# Is Facebook C# SDK usable with Silverlight?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I've been trying the "facebook developer toolkit" out for a few hours (vs Silverlight 4) without any success. I've dropped it and found Facebook C# SDK instead.

Is this SDK usable with Silverlight?
Are there any samples?

Regards,
Maciek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Facebook C# SDK does work with Silverlight. We have samples complete and hopefully we can get them posted on codeplex today. It does work though and should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: The samples are up on http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com. Let me know how they work for you. We are still finishing some stuff up, but I wanted to get them up for everyone asap.